# NSString text height not getting correct value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

Not getting text height correctly if having new line correctly ("\n")

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

CGRect rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(textWidth, MAXFLOAT)
                                 options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                              attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:textFont,
                                           NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:
                                               paragraphStyle}
                                 context:nil];
```

Even tried with other approaches like size butI am getting same values my text is having "\n" new line character as well.

Answer (score 1):

`NSLineBreakByClipping` is what you use when you want to autoshrink the text to fit. If you're trying to adjust the view to fit the text, then you'll want `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`.

Also, if you're getting `textWidth` from the current width of a control, be sure to get the width in `viewWillAppear` or later, not in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to round the rect value. See the example bellow.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

CGRect rect = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(textWidth, MAXFLOAT)
                                 options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                              attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:textFont,
                                           NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:
                                               paragraphStyle}
                                 context:nil];



rect = CGRectIntegral(rect);
```

Comment: I am facing this issue in iPhone 6s Plus only

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `firstLineHeadIndent` with some value if you want to use `NSMutableParagraphStyle` because it is considered as `paragraph`.

Without `firstLineHeadIndent`, `NSMutableParagraphStyle` will not work!

So, set negligible value something like below and your issue may solve!!

```
 paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 0.0001f;
```

**Update :**

In one of my project i am managing this something like below,

```
    // I am using this commented code with my custom class

//    CustomLabel *staticTextLabel = [[CustomLabel alloc]init];
//    NSString *title;
//    
//    staticTextLabel.topInset = 0.0;
//    staticTextLabel.leftInset = 10.0;
//    staticTextLabel.rightInset = 10.0;
//    staticTextLabel.bottomInset = 0.0;


// you can use below code
UILabel *staticTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
NSString *title = @"your string here";


NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyles = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyles.alignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;      //justified text
paragraphStyles.firstLineHeadIndent = 0.0001f;                //must have a value to make it work


UIFont *myFont = staticTextLabel.font;

NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyles, NSFontAttributeName : myFont};
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: title attributes: attributes];


// set width according to your case
CGSize maximuLabelSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 40 -20, FLT_MAX); //20 is padding space (left right)


CGRect textRect = [attributedString boundingRectWithSize:maximuLabelSize
                                                 options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin| NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading
                                                 context:nil];


CGFloat height2 = textRect.size.height ;
NSLog(@"height 2 is %f",height2);


// manage width according to your case and height also if any padding is there
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(20, 10, self.view.frame.size.width - 40, height2 +20); // 20 is for top bottom padding
staticTextLabel.frame = newFrame;
staticTextLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
staticTextLabel.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor]CGColor];
staticTextLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
staticTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

And it is working in every device. you can try it!!

Comment: I am facing this issue in iPhone 6s Plus only

Comment: Thanks Ketan tried with above code that u shared, still it is not working is there any way without using AttributeString